# How can I drag-and-drop an `org-mode` header onto the Mac desktop?

Tags: osx, drag-and-drop

John Kitchin has a [terrific video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahqKXbBVjpQ) on modifying the default drag-n-drop behavior, going from the Mac Finder onto an Emacs buffer.

I would like to implement the opposite behavior: dragging an `org-mode` header onto another mac app (specifically the Apple Calendar).

Specifically, I want to use the mouse to drag an org-mode headline onto the calendar so that, and in doing so, create a calendar event that looks something like:

```
[ ] item to do
```

which includes a link back to the task in org-mode in the calendar event’s note field.

How can I do that?

Comment: You should add a description of what you want to happen when you drag an org mode headline onto the calendar app.

Comment: Okay done. Thanks @Omar.